# Which Apache cassandra version to use for production

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.1

We are exploring apache cassandra and are going to use it for Production soon.

We are going to use mostly Datastax community edition of apache cassandra.

But after reading : 
http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/cassandra-2-2-3-0-and-beyond/ 
https://www.pythian.com/blog/cassandra-version-production/

With this sentence from above blog “If you don’t mind facing serious bugs and contribute to the development pick 3.x”

I am confused about which version to opt for our production deployment ?
Just need to know whether 3.5.0 and 3.0.6 are production ready.

Datastax community : 3.5.0 from http://www.planetcassandra.org/cassandra/ 
Datastax community : 3.0.6 from 
http://www.planetcassandra.org/archived-versions-of-datastaxs-distribution-of-apache-cassandra/

or 
Datastax community : 2.2.6 from 
http://www.planetcassandra.org/archived-versions-of-datastaxs-distribution-of-apache-cassandra/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version provided by datastax is supposed to be stable and production ready. You have an application to monitor your cluster, which is nice if you don't have any ops that knows about cassandra in the first place, and you can pay to get support.
However, you don't have the latest version of Cassandra, and you can miss interesting features.

As for Cassandra 3.x, as said above, you get more features (for example JSON support) and better performance, but if you find a critical bug and can't fix it, you can only writes a ticket and hope they will take care of it quickly. **Yet it is production ready** and this could work well for you.

In conclusion, go for the latest version only if you need a special feature, or if you have the developers in your team to back your choice. Go for Datastax if you want something that works with less effort.

Comment: I want something that works with less efforts. So datastax 3.5 community is the latest from them. We might opt for that.

Comment: http://docs.datastax.com/en/landing_page/doc/landing_page/current.html. There I see a more recent datastax, but it runs on cassandra 2.1